# e/trace : error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: android, trace

I work on the project android application ..
My application uses `file.txt` for the purposes of a process.
I found an error opening trace file:

```
 No such file or directory (2) when running my application.
```

The manifest I have complete internet access permissions.
I save the `file.txt` in `res/raw/file.txt`
there is no error in the code line.
I use a OS 4.1 (jelly bean)
android"sdk" 21

Any help would be appreciated.

### then I tried it once again by using a virtual android 4.2.2  ... but the results are also errors

```
public List<String> read() {
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {          
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/raw/katadasar.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        // System.out.println(strLine);
        ls.add(strLine.trim().toLowerCase());
        }
        //Close the input stream
        inputStreamReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return ls;
}
```

### logcat

```
 07-24 03:38:38.710: D/dalvikvm(790): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
 07-24 03:38:39.060: I/dalvikvm(790): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK     version 9...
 07-24 03:38:39.470: E/Trace(790): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 07-24 03:38:39.700: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 8% free 2403K/2608K,           paused 29ms, total 31ms
 07-24 03:38:39.720: I/dalvikvm-heap(790): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.944MB for 1536016-byte allocation
 07-24 03:38:39.770: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3902K/4112K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
 07-24 03:38:39.820: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3902K/4112K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 55ms
 07-24 03:38:40.120: D/(790): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a18c160, tid 790
 07-24 03:38:45.919: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1505K, 38% free 2808K/4484K, paused 12ms+57ms, total 256ms
 07-24 03:38:54.389: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 121K, 31% free 3104K/4484K, paused 73ms+95ms, total 300ms
 07-24 03:38:58.909: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 269K, 28% free 3255K/4484K, paused 75ms+9ms, total 150ms
 07-24 03:38:58.909: D/dalvikvm(790): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 69ms
 07-24 03:38:59.389: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 202K, 23% free 3477K/4484K, paused 75ms+8ms, total 138ms
 07-24 03:38:59.389: D/dalvikvm(790): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 57ms
 07-24 03:38:59.669: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 575K, 24% free 3409K/4484K, paused 74ms+8ms, total 144ms
 07-24 03:38:59.679: D/dalvikvm(790): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
 07-24 03:39:00.530: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 23% free 3492K/4484K, paused 29ms+89ms, total 223ms
```

Comment: Please, attach your logcat's output and share the code where you are trying to access the file.

Comment: please help ... I really need to resolve this error

Comment: This question is unanswerable as the posted error is a spurious issue in the debugger, and not the cause of any crash.  You would need to post the logcat through to the actual crash message if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file in your raw folder, yo can try this:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.katadasar);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Also, you should change the code in your catch from what you have:

```
catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

to this, to print the correct error:

```
catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
    Log.e("YourTag", "Error:" +  e.getLocalizedMessage() );
}
```

Try the above code (with the corret error logcat output) and if it does not work, please update the logcat output to try to locate the error